# Poco Library, both HTTP and HTTPS server

Tags: c++, http, https, poco-libraries

I was wondering if is it possible to have server that is able to answer to both http and https requests using Poco Library. Probably one option would be to run 2 servers binding different port, is there any other way only using 1 port?

I have implemented https and http servers previously using Poco Library 1.09.

Comment: By default most HTTP(S) clients connect to port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. So which one port do you want to listen on?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Why does it matter? You could open port 8080 for HTTP and HTTPS. AFAIK HTTP and HTTPS are always inside a TCP packet. The server always knows the beginning of the message. If it's encrypted, pass the HTTPS request to the HTTPS server. If it's unencrypted, pass it to the HTTP server.

Comment: @jabaa: I'm trying to get the OP to clarify the question with more details. It's not clear exactly what is wanted. How can a listener on a single port know whether it's processing an HTTP request or a TLS packet? In fact, it can be done, but it's tricky, probably too fragile, and thus not a good idea.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The question is pretty clear and your comment is the answer without Poco. It's possible but tricky. The actual question is, if it's possible with Poco.

Answer (score 1):

This would most commonly be done by standing up an nginx front end to proxy the request. The advantage of that way is that it's quick to configure and all the standard tools people have for managing https with nginx will work for you -- things like certificate management.

This also isolates your program. It doesn't listen on a public address, just the localhost address, which reduces your security attack surface.

Or if you're going to host at AWS or a similar service, you can let the load balancer handle https, and your program can just worry about http.

Comment: How can you bind HTTPS and HTTP to the same port using nginx?

Comment: He's almost certainly going to need to use 2 ports no matter what he does. But the browser expects 80 and 443 respectively already, if you don't also specify a port, as do all the REST tools I have ever used in code. But maybe you have a better solution. This is Stack Overflow. You should share your answer.

Comment: No, you don't need two ports. You can open one port, analyze the packet and decide whether it's an HTTP or HTTPS packet. The question is whether you can achieve it using POCO and I don't know the answer.

Comment: @jabaa That sounds like fun and is quite unexpected by anyone using this API. His question doesn't demand 1 port, just asks if it's possible. The only ways I know how to provide HTTP / HTTPS are clear -- 2 ports, either two listeners via Poco or use an engine. If I were doing it, I would use nginx as outlined.

Comment: Yes, the question asks, if it's possible and it seems to be the only question. I can't find the answer here. Maybe, it's an academical or theoretical question, but your answer should answer it.

Comment: @jabaa I wouldn't consider my answer to be the best possible. I looked at his very first sentence, which is, "I was wondering if is it possible to have server that is able to answer to both http and https requests using Poco Library.". And I explained a different way that could solve the goal, and explained why I would do it that way. I imagine with Poco you would create two listeners, but I've never created an https listener with Poco and wouldn't want to have to, for the reasons I listed in my original answer.